# run and initiate javascript code only after Vue is fully loaded and initialized

Tags: javascript, vue.js

There is an issue that I'm dealing with
there is an external service that is an online chat service that should be initiate
this service need to be initiate with an addEventListener that call raychat_ready

I need help to use it in the vue component

for the begining I can share the real sample with you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>main-logo.png" />
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong
        >We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work
        properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to
        continue.</strong
      >
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!--BEGIN RAYCHAT CODE-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      !(function () {
        function t() {
          var t = document.createElement("script");
          (t.type = "text/javascript"),
            (t.async = !0),
            localStorage.getItem("rayToken")
              ? (t.src =
                  "https://app.raychat.io/scripts/js/" +
                  o +
                  "?rid=" +
                  localStorage.getItem("rayToken") +
                  "&href=" +
                  window.location.href)
              : (t.src =
                  "https://app.raychat.io/scripts/js/" +
                  o +
                  "?href=" +
                  window.location.href);
          var e = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
          e.parentNode.insertBefore(t, e);
        }
        var e = document,
          a = window,
          o =
            "%= NODE_ENV %" === "development"
              ? "development-token"
              : "production-token";
        "complete" == e.readyState
          ? t()
          : a.attachEvent
          ? a.attachEvent("onload", t)
          : a.addEventListener("load", t, !1);
      })();
    </script>
    <!--END RAYCHAT CODE-->
  </body>
</html>
```

My issue is that I need to initiate the app without calling this

```js
window.addEventListener('raychat_ready', () => {
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  if (user) {
    window.Raychat.setUser({
      updateOnce: false,
      about: `id: ${user.id}`,
      name: user.name,
      phone: user.mobile,
      avatar: user.avatar
        ? user.avatar
        : 'https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20190223/ourlarge/pngtree-vector-avatar-icon-png-image_695765.jpg',
    });
  }
});
```

I don't want to put my codes in the addEventListener and call raychat event

If anyone has any idea I would be happy to share it with me :)

Comment: Generally you need to load third-party script inside a component, not the opposite way. E.g through vue-plugin-load-script , with script url that you can see on rendered page, this way you won't need this pasted piece of code that just creates `<script src>`

Comment: Can you provide your `vue.js` code? However, if I understand it correctly, `I need help to use it in the vue component`. You can use the `mounted` lifecycle hook in vue.js, and put the code that you want to run after the vue component is initiated inside it.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks for your response. do you have any idea how should I render script of this third-party script inside my component?

Comment: See the previous comment, I specifically named a lib that can do this